# Allow double-byte space in Regex

Tags: c#, regex, double-byte

I have a regex on my C# code to check if the name that end user entered is valid, my regex deny double-byte characters like double-byte space.

The double-byte space like the space between quotation “　“ .

My regex: `@"^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}' \.\-]+$"`.

I'm already tried to edit this regex to accept double-byte space, but I did not reach meaningful result.

So please if any one can edit this regex to accept double-byte space, I will be thankful for him.

Comment: Replace space with `\s` (any whitespace) or `\p{Zs}` (all horizontal whitespace without `\t`), or `\p{Zs}\t` (to inlcude a tab).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much, the second  one (\p{Zs}) is work.

Comment: is work is good, and @WiktorStribiżew if there was an award in regex excellence, you should get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace a literal space with a pattern that matches any horizontal Unicode whitespace and in .NET regex, it can be achieved with `\p{Zs}`.

```
@"^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Zs}'.-]+$"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BM%7D%5Cp%7BN%7D%5Cp%7BZs%7D%27.-%5D%2B%24&i=Word%E3%80%80123).

Note this pattern does not match a TAB char. If you need to match a TAB, too, you just need to add it,

```
@"^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Zs}\t'.-]+$"
```

Note you do not need to escape `.` and `-` in this regex. `.` inside square brackets is not any special regex metacharacter and `-` is not special when it is placed at the end of the character class.

Comment: I found a problem in my regex that the regex accept the name that contains spaces only, how can I solve this?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdeen `@"^(?!\s+$)[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Zs}\t'.-]+$"`

Comment: At first thank you so much, your edit solve the name that contains spaces only, but when I tried to check the name that contains double-byte spaces only, the regex still accept it.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdeen It is [impossible](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!%5cs%2b%24%29%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bM%7d%5cp%7bN%7d%5cp%7bZs%7d%27.-%5d%2b%24&i=%e3%80%80%e3%80%80%e3%80%80%e3%80%80%e3%80%80)

Comment: Im check the regex here https://regex101.com/r/fx0UW8/1/ and its return the double-byte spaces name as match

Comment: @MahmoudAbdeen regex101 does not support .NET regex. Do not rely on regex101 when you check a regex that you intend to use with .NET regex engine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230226/discussion-between-mahmoud-abdeen-and-wiktor-stribizew).